# Atmel Attiny 104 - Arduino support

Tags: c, arduino, atmelstudio

From what I have gathered, you can implement a new chip in Arduino by editing boards and arduino_pins.h

From what I can see, AtTiny84 is pretty similar to 104, but the pin out and pin functions are slightly different.

My question is:
How can I edit Arduino_pins.h to match that of AtTiny104 chip?

*I tried programming with Atmel studio but my comprehension of C of that magnitude is shallow so I prefer doing it with Arduino ide.

My project is simple:
If inputs i1 high or i2 high or i3 (analog value) < 700

then output o1 is high

Else 
if i4 is high
Then o1 is low
Else
O1 is high

Arduino support or atmel studio support much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a core for the '84 yet?

Comment: Also, 32 bytes of SRAM will make it painful to use the Arduino libraries on.